# How to pass string id's through intent?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

i want to send integer value  through intents , and access it on another activity ... i tried using the following code .. but its not working..!!

```
mCheatButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.cheat_button);
    mCheatButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                mCheatButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                mIsCheater = false;
                int mCurrentIndex=2;
                Intent i = new Intent(quizactivity.this,       CheatActivity.class);
                i.putExtra(CheatActivity.EXTRA_ANSWER_IS_TRUE, mCurrentIndex);
                startActivityForResult(i, 0);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
            }

        }
    });


SECOND ACTIVITY:
          mShowAnswer = (Button)findViewById(R.id.showAnswerButton);
    mShowAnswer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(extras == null)

            {        mAnswerIsTrue= 0;
                updateanswer(mAnswerIsTrue);

            }

            else

            {        

                mAnswerIsTrue= extras.getInt(EXTRA_ANSWER_IS_TRUE);
                updateanswer(mAnswerIsTrue);
            }

            updateanswer(mAnswerIsTrue);
        }
    });

 public void updateanswer(int q){
    mAnswerTextView.setText(solution[q].getA());
    setAnswerShownResult(true);
}
```

please help me solve it out..!!

i want to send integer value  through intents , and access it on another activity ... i tried using the following code .. but its not working..!!

what is the error in above code.. i cant really understand...!!

Comment: You haven't yet told us anything about the problem you are having when running this code. Also, your title mentions String but your body only talks about int. Also, having empty `catch{}` blocks is **still** a bad idea

Comment: be more clear about the problem - do you get it once? Never? Does it crash? Do you never have any extras?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In you second activity you need to do

```
int i = getIntent().getExtras().getInt(CheatActivity.EXTRA_ANSWER_IS_TRUE)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is on your second activity, I guess.

```
Intent extras = getIntent();
int yourInt = extras.getIntExtra(EXTRA_ANSWER_IS_TRUE, -1);
```